# PHP/Server caching csv file

Tags: php, caching, server

I wrote a cron which is downloading CSV file from given URL and update database basing on that file contents. The URL doesn't change, the file under URL does.

My client informed me that updating database is delayed and sent me current file to compare with server's one. I found out that file on server is updated with delay, it may be few hours or 1-2 days. It looks like server is using some cached CSV file instead of downloading new one. I changed url by adding "?v=".time() but it didn't solve the problem.

My question is - is it my server caching file or server under that URL is sending me the wrong file (they may check IP and send cached file instead of the new one). How to check it? How to fix it?

Comment: Whether *your* cron is caching the file only you know, as you've written it. It may certainly be that you're getting a cached version of it; if the remote server doesn't want to send you a new version, there's little you can do. Have you tried inspecting the network response more closely for cache headers/contents?

Comment: How are you downloading it?.. PHP wont cache it by default.

Comment: My code is simply "file_get_contents('url_here.csv'')". I'm not caching anything myself.

Comment: Ok, the problem was... my client :) He provided me the wrong url (to csv instead of php generator).

Answer (score -1):

try to add a pseudorandom value at the end of the url so it would always look for a fresh (not cached) version

```
file_get_contents('url_here.csv?' . date('Ymd'))"
```

this should work the same way with "cache busting" for JS/CSS

Comment: If you read my question carefully you would see that I already did it.